# Delayed Post to DataFlow

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow, dataflow

When posting an item to a `TPL DataFlow`, is there any mechanism that can allow for a delayed post?

```
public partial class BasicDataFlowService
{
    private readonly ActionBlock<string> workerBlock;

    public BasicDataFlowService()
    {
        workerBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(file => DoWork(file), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 32
        });
    }

    partial void DoWork(string fileName);

    private void AddToDataFlow(string file)
    {
        workerBlock.Post(file);
    }
}
```

Within `AddToDataFlow`, I would like to be able to specify a delay before the item is processed (e.g. if we've decided we want to defer the processing for 30 seconds).

I did consider using a `TransFormBlock` with `new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(1000);`, e.g.

```
var requeueBlock = new TransformBlock<string, string>(file =>
{
    new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(1000);
    return file;
});

requeueBlock.LinkTo(workerBlock);
```

However, this would appear to be consuming a thread needlessly that could be used by other blocks in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to store the [`ManualResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) as a singleton, otherwise all the threads will got their own object to wait for, and your approach wouldn't work.

Secondly, do consider the [`ManualResetEventSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.aspx) version instead of heavy [`ManualResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx), if you need to do a synchronization inside one `AppDomain` in your pipeline.

If you want to reuse the cores of your machine without useless waiting, you should look into [`SpinWait`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinwait.aspx) lightweight structure. You may find [Joseph Albahari' article](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_SpinWait) useful in this case:

```
// singleton variable
bool _proceed;

var requeueBlock = new TransformBlock<string, string>(file =>
{
    var spinWait = new SpinWait();
    while (!_proceed)
    {
        // ensure we have the latest _proceed value
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        // try to spin for a while
        // after some spins, yield to another thread
        spinWait.SpinOnce();
    }
    return file;
});
```

[`SpinWait`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinwait.aspx) internally decides, how to yeild: with [`Sleep(0)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx), [`Sleep(1)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) or [`Yield`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.yield.aspx) method calls, so it's quite effective for your case.

Answer (score 0):

To add a delay before posting a value to the `workerBlock` you can simply insert a delay and await it before posting the value. If your `workerBlock` has a bounded capacity you can `await SendAsync`. A few options to accomplish the goal:

```
private async Task AddToDataflow(string file, TimeSpan delay) {
    await Task.Delay(delay);
    await workerBlock.SendAsync(file);
}

private async Task AddToDataflow(string file) {
    var delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    await Task.Delay(delay);
    await workerBlock.SendAsync(file);
}

private async void AddToDataflow(string file) {
    var delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    await Task.Delay(delay);
    workerBlock.Post(file);
}
```